# how about use shared memory to share data in a program

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I want to write a "embedded control system", on Linux

In order to make it easy to update in the future, i think multi-process is better than muti-thread

so, this system maybe separate into 3 program

1. "process", read some input data from others and do some calculation, then save the result to shared memory
2. "display", read instant data from shared memory and choose some data to display on UI(written by Qt)
3. "database", read instant data from shared memory and save them in a period, data will be saved in binary files at first, and maybe use sqlite instead in the future

and nore, maybe i will add a web server to read the instant data and show it through the browser

here is the question:

1. is multi-process really better multi-thread?
2. If use multi-process, how about use shared memory, is there any disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is multi-process really better multi-thread?

Depends on what you want to do. Multiprocessing enforces a strict separation between system components, allowing for various parts to run with different credentials. It does require a more complicated communication mechanism than multithreading and incurs some overhead.

> If use multi-process, how about use shared memory, is there any disadvantage.

The main disadvantage, compared to the obvious alternative of using sockets, is that it limits your entire system to running on a single host. No distributed computing.

Comment: thanks a lot, if use socket, is that impossible(or hard) to share data between 3 or more programs?

Comment: @newkedison: you'll have to send all relevant data to all relevant processes. You'll also need to design a communication protocol, but you'll equally need that for the shmem-based design.

Comment: shared memory can "broadcast" data, but socket is point-to-point(UDP multicast is unreliable and depend on a router)

Comment: @newkedison: that's true. Shared memory is also faster for transferring big amounts of data. You were asking for its *disadvantage*, though :)

Comment: ^-^, thanks for your help, because i have to decide which one to use, so i need to know both advantage and disadvantage of them. seems that shared memory is more suite me.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using Qt, which is [suitable for embedded systems](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Embedded_Linux). Great.

It has good APIs for TCP sockets and *nix sockets, and good data streaming protocols. Unless you demand absolutely scorching performance, I would err on the side of secure, separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

The upside of three processes is that the protected address space prevents unwanted communications between the processes.

The upside of three processes is that the protected address space hinders wanted communications between the processes.

Inter-process communication is slower and more difficult to manage than inter-thread comms.

Comment: after google for the knowledge of processes communication. i found shared memory is the most quickly and easy way. is it really so slow?